# Silverstripe: MemberAuthenticator::authenticate() fails when password has hash sign

Tags: silverstripe

I have following piece of code in -

```
public function apilogin(){
        $auth = array(
                    "Email" => $this->requestParams["email"],
                    "Password" => $this->requestParams["pwd"]
                );

        $log = MemberAuthenticator::authenticate($auth);

        if($log){
           //login successful
        }else{
           //Error in logging in
        }
}
```

**The Problem**

This method works well except when password has hash "#" sign. I checked multiple times. It works if login is correct and password doesnot have hash sign. But it miserably fails if password has hash even if password is correct.
I m aware of the fact that, its likely for security reason hash is escaped (as it treats as comment)

Is there any fix for this? Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. Can you file an issue at https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues ?

Comment: Hmmm hashes should be fine, you can have a hash and login using the default SilverStripe login...

Comment: Does "requestParams" come from the URL? If so, are you correctly encoding it before you send it to SilverStripe (and subsequently decoding it?)

Comment: @RobbieAverill, It doesn't work even if Username and password are hard coded.

Comment: url encoding and decoding solve the issue.